# How to set order of executing tests in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i want to ask you if it's possible to set order of executing tests?
For eg.

I have 3 definition of tests in class

```
def test_1():
    ....

def test_2():
    ....

def test_3():
    ...
```

and I don't know why but Selenium start executing them from test_3.
How can I change this?

Comment: How do you call them?

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Example*

```
class Main:
    # constructor of Main class
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialization of the Strings
        self.String1 = "Hello"
        self.String2 = "World"

    def test_1(self):
        print("test_1 : ", self.String2)
        return

    def test_2(self):
        print("test_2 : ", self.String1)
        return

    def test_3(self):
        print("test_3 : ", self.String1)
        return


# Instance of Class Main
Object = Main()

# Calling Functions
Object.test_1()
Object.test_2()
Object.test_3()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to run these 3 in a particular order (1, 2, 3). 
If that is the case, then I would wrap these 3 into a method, like so:

```
def run_tests():
     test_1()
     test_2()
     test_3()

run_tests()
```

That way, it will run in order.
Is this something you are looking for?